# How to create an if statement which loops until the if statement is no longer satisfied

Tags: c#, loops, conditional-statements, control-flow

In my Windows-Phone application I need to use a condition which needs to run for so long until it is no longer satisfied.

How can I create some form of logic-loop? I have tried using an `if` statement but that only goes round once.

I'm fairly new to c# and aren't sure of all of the different logic conditions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is Buffer waiting and should never done!

Comment: `if` is never used for loops, in C# and any other language that I'm aware of, not even in the Turing machine, it's just a wrong construct for the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for a `while`-loop:

```
while(condition)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Or possibly a `do-while`-loop:

```
do
{
    // do stuff
} while (condition);
```

The difference here is that the `while`-loop always evaluates it's condition before the first iteration while the `do-while`-loop evaluates it after the first iteration.

**Further Reading**

- [while (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx)
- [do (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx)